# PUSH notifications on Android with Windows Azure

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have spent a long while searching for a guide on implementing PUSH for Android with Azure with no luck. Is this just not available yet?

If not, is there an alternative way I can implement this, perhaps by using HTTP Requests from the server side to another service that can Push to android?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure supports [push notification through Mobile Services](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-ios/) which is still a preview feature. And it currently only supports Windows Store, Windows Phone and iOS apps. Support for iOS hasn't been available for that long which could mean that Microsoft is also working on other platforms like Android.

Your other option is to build something yourself, use existing tools like GCM or to use a third-party provider like [Pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com). The great thing about Pushwoosh is that they have a free plan, they support Android and [they have a REST API](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method/messages/create) which can be called from Windows Azure to create the notifications.

Comment: Thanks! Would you also recommned urbanairship or parse.com?

Comment: Urbanairship doesn't have a free plan you can start with so I would say no. Parse.com on the other hand seems to give you a lot in the free plan so I would definitely look at it.

Comment: Another 3rd party provider is Push.IO. But it's really not hard to do it yourself (we did). There's also a library, PushSharp, that will handle almost all the available push services including Android.  https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: It looks to me like the remote API is limited to paid accounts only. https://cp.pushwoosh.com/products

Comment: I find Parse to be the best option for push. They are the most straightforward with pricing, have great docs, and lots of code examples!

Comment: I think that you need to use a Mobile Service in Azure. You should be able to use the Push option on the Mobile Service to connect to Google Cloud Messaging which connects to the Android client. GCM authentication requires that you add the IP address of the Mobile Service to a white list.  At the moment I don't know the IP address of my mobile service. This could be because it's in Free Mode.

I have tried accessing GCM from my azure website but it always fails authentication.  I have tried adding the website IP address but it does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading online documentation seems to suggest that you need to use a Mobile Service in Azure. You should be able to use the Push option on the Mobile Service to connect to Google Cloud Messaging which connects to the Android client. GCM authentication requires that you add the IP address of the Mobile Service to a white list.

However there is an easier way...
I can access the GCM API directly from my azure website (after adding the IP address which is not available in free mode).  To see my code look [here](https://github.com/fireydude/GCM_Sender)